# How to get current number of connections of an akka-http application

Tags: akka, monitoring, prometheus, akka-http

I want to get the **current** number of connections from within an akka-http application. Is there any way to get hold of it?

The end goal is to be able to publish it to prometheus regularly for monitoring the load of the service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Kamon` ? It has a nice build in `Context` instrumentation that you can use to have the metrics you want to use.

Documentation here : https://kamon.io/docs/latest/core/context/